# System for levels of sacrifices?

Tags: korban

The Pesach offering is not kodshim, it is kalim (not the highest level of holiness but lower holiness level).  What is the system underlying which kobanot (offerings) are at what level?  I am seeking the logic behind the levels of korbanot.